# Can Chrome be prevented from doing page refresh when exiting a full-screen Adobe Flash session?

Tags: google-chrome, video

On a Windows 10 desktop, I watch videos using the Chrome browser.  The Crunchyroll site streams videos that use the Adobe Flash extension.  I watch them in full-screen mode, then collapse the video to its normal-box within a browser page.  Most of this time, this leads to a delay as a page refresh occurs, and Crunchyroll reloads the video.  (Fortunately Crunchyroll remembers the time mark you were at.)  The reload is unnecessary and wastes time.  The few times it does not occur, the video just smoothly keeps on playing.

**So, is there a way to tell Chrome not to bother refreshing a page when full-screen video mode has been exited?**

BTW, this same thing will infrequently happen when watching a YouTube video, which are streamed using the HTML5 player.  Even though it happens much less frequently, it is particularly annoying because the page refresh will often cause a new ad to play.

Comment: Usually exiting fullscreen mode does not trigger a reload, at all. There are only 2 key-binds for a reload: F5 and CTRL-R.

Comment: @GiantTree I believe you concerning your system.  On mine, though, Flash causes a page reload almost every time it is collapsed from full-screen to window-pane mode.  You probably understand already, but I am not talking about the window itself being collapsed from maximized to normal size, but the video pane only.

Comment: Could you test your issue with different browsers (Firefox or Edge) and different methods of entering/leaving fullscreen mode? Also try just resizing.

Comment: @GiantTree I'll experiment with Edge, although my main goal is to stop this occurrence within Chrome.  But as you suspect, I might learn something useful while experimenting.

Comment: @GiantTree   I'm still not certain I've explained the problem well.  "Resizing" implies I am changing the size of the window.  I am not.  I am expanding the video pane withing the window to occupy the full screen.  I.e., it is not a browser function, but a Flash or HTML5 player function.  Then a side effect of collapsing the video back to within the pane is that it often causes a browser page refresh.  At any rate, resizing a Crunchyroll window with a Flash pane has no effect on the pane.  Resizing a YouTube window with HTML5 video pane will cause the pane to resize, but not a window refresh.

Answer (score 0):

No. The described behavior is normal.

---

I also asked a [similar question on Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-983531/browser-unnecessarily-reloads-anime-and-manga-pages) (CR), where the occurrence is most prevalent. A member named *beardfist* (who has developed an HTML5 Player for CR) was one of the responders:

> The problems you are describing are a symptom of the auto-play (or perhaps more accurately auto-advance) implementation that CR (and YT to some extent) use. Basically for anime while you are full screen, if you allow it to advance to the next episode it will load the next stream all nice and neat without making you hit full screen again (this is relatively new for CR).. When that happens, the rest of the page hasn't been changed at all, so when you come out of full screen, it loads the correct page for that episode. Since the only part of the episode page that is modular is the comment section, with the rest being sent as a big chunk, it really is the easiest way to do it, even if it isn't the best experience.
>
> ...
>
> While it is possible to implement the video player and manga viewer in such a way that this refresh doesn't happen, doing so in the current flash versions would not be worth the time it would take, imo. There are HTML5 versions of both that are in various stages of in the works and while that may be something on the todo list, most likely they will opt to still have the page refresh when you come out of full screen just as youtube does.

I'll inform him about this SE question so he'll know of this extensive quote, and have the opportunity to comment if he so wishes.